# Reading the lines of file1 and insert them in between file2 line for every match

Tags: linux

I need help to achieve this task of matching every line of file-1 and inserting them in between all the commands in file-2.

### File-1(has 200+ entries nd some with quotes if spaces are used)

```
 LES000A4304_UAT 
 LES000A2287_UAT 
 LES000A4273_UAT 
 LES000A4298_UAT 
 LES000A4285_UAT
 "VES00134RT OIT"
 "ALL LES0A PORT13200"
 LES000A23473_UAT
 LES000A2073_UAT
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

### File-2(has 4 command lines)

```
 set setting target name devices 01245678
 set setting target name devices 04532342
 set setting target name devices 03424524
 set setting target name devices 09823424
```

The objective is to match every element(including the one with "") in file1 to be inserted in between the command string in file 2. So the output looks like this

### Output

```
set setting target name LES000A4304_UAT devices 01245678
 set setting target name LES000A4304_UAT devices 04532342
 set setting target name LES000A4304_UAT devices 03424524
 set setting target name LES000A4304_UAT devices 09823424
 
 OR 
 
 set setting target name "VES00134RT OIT" devices 01245678
 ..
 ..
 ..
```

How can we achieve this using awk or sed

Comment: Could you please also format your example data as it were code? Otherwise symbols could be misplaced or misinterpreted.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) --  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  --  [I Downvoted Because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution to my question using python for iterating through list

```
    infile = open("file1.txt", "r")

for x in infile:
    print('cmd1',x,'rest')
    print('cmd2',x,'rest')
infile.close()
```